# How do I make the Scoreboard on the side not be visible when the Debug HUD is open?

Tags: minecraft-fabric

[image: Fabric 1.16.5] [image: Client-Sided Mod] [image: Java Coding Language]

I'm working on a 1.16.5 Minecraft client-side mod and I am trying to get the scoreboard to be invisible when the `Debug HUD` is visible. I have a basic mixin to the scoreboard's rendering function but I need to be able to check for whether the `DebugHud` is visible or not.

Code:

```
@Mixin(InGameHud.class)
public class MScoreboardHUD {
    @Inject(at = @At("HEAD"), method = "renderScoreboardSidebar")
    private void init(CallbackInfo info) {
        // soon
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found `MinecraftClient.options.debugEnabled`, currently testing to see if it's what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Using `MinecraftClient.options.debugEnabled` will tell you whether the F3 menu is active.

### Final Code

This uses `client` as the `MinecraftClient` object, and `info.cancel()` to cancel the scoreboard render

```
@Mixin(InGameHud.class)
public class MScoreboardHUD {
    @Inject(at = @At("HEAD"), method = "renderScoreboardSidebar")
    private void init(CallbackInfo info) {
        if (client.options.debugEnabled) {
            info.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```